# ffmpeg doesn't recognize the local key file for decrypting a m3u8

Tags: python, encryption, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Ok so here is the situation.

I have a m3u8 file which is encrypted using AES-128. Using a simple python script I download the m3u8 and the key file and then serves it over the local network with the aid of SimpleHTTPServer. Then I run a separate shell script to get the m3u8 and key file from the local server and it get the job done without any problems.

Now instead of getting the files from the local server, I want to decrypt them locally from the command line. So I replaced the key path of the m3u8 from,

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://example.com/key"
```

to

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="file://local/path/to/video.key"
```

And when executed the following from the command line,

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -allowed_extensions ALL -i playlist.m3u8 "output.mp4"
```

It gives me these two errors and exits.

```
Unable to open key file file://local/path/to/video.key
playlist.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Now my question is why ffmpeg doesn't give any errors when I serve the key file over a local server, and why things get changed when I do it this way? Any help maybe?